# facebook authentication via Client SDK - Security Concept

Tags: facebook, api, authentication

I think I don't fully understand the way the facebook OAuth-API handles authentication. As far as I understand, it works basically like this (client being an Android phone, my server a standard LAMP-setup):
[fb auth http://i.imagebanana.com/img/hvlsb2dp/fbAuth.png](http://i.imagebanana.com/img/hvlsb2dp/fbAuth.png)

Now the issue is, the client can of course fake step number 3 by submitting a wrong userID to my server - for example if my server responds to the request http://server.com/getConfidentialData.php?fbID=%FBID% , and the user manages to get the fb-userID of someone else, he could just put that into the request and he'd get the data that belongs to someone else.

If I use the PHP-SDK, how can it know whether my user is logged in in the Android-App or not?

Is that the way it's supposed to work, or am I missing something?

Thanks, 
David.

Answer (score 1):

The only true solution:

The moment you have a server with private user data and not everything is on Facebook, you need to do the server-side login which is not hard to implement once you understand the flow.

Check the diagram at Facebook and follow the guidelines they provide in this example and you are good to go.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem... And the same sensation, but since you don't have any answers I'll take you around what I found.

I have designed the following solution:

I send to my server the fb userID, his e-mail (as to identify him in my server) and his access token (everything through https as if it was an special login call).

From my server I try out the access token, and if this one works(*) I log&update/register the user in my server too.

(*) I defined works first as if I could access the user e-mail, but then any other app with that permission could impersonate my user, so now I extend the token life which only works if the token comes form my app.

I hope this helps, and meanwhile, if anyone could have a real solution to this problem and explain to us how others avoid this, I'd be grateful.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for sharing your method, but I can't really imagine that the facebook guys didn't thought of something more complete - I mean, this is THE most central auth-issue, so they should should be a possibility to do that in an elegant and secure way. On the other hand, if I look at their mess of an API...

Comment: @David I know, this is a 3-way auth so facebook server and client need to make contact with each other but that enver happens in any of the three scenarios facebook shows: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/login-architecture/ I mean... either u don't know which client called you through facebook in server side login, or u can't trust your client saying hey! I've logged in through facebook with this user, let me in! in the cleint side js sdk login... I mean, my method is the only one where each side authenticates the othes... so far. Any errors on my way?

Comment: Well wouldn't it be possible by using server-side-login and then retrieving the userID via the Open-Graph-API (/me object), without any Client-FB-Contact after he once clicked the redirect_uri in the 'fb-official' app login form? The obvious disadvantage would be that he had to this every time he starts the app on a mobile device, if the Web-View has no access to the Standard Browser's cookies or the user is not logged in in the browser (which, I guess, most people that use the fb-App aren't)

Comment: Probably works... I can't believe we don't have a true answer to this question! Only work-arounds.